# How to get exact lock string from WOPI LOCK request

Tags: ms-wopi

How to find lock string from wopi client as **X-Wopi-Lock** contains long string representing the json as given below.

In 1st lock request for same file I got,

> **{"S":"899d5d58-d6bd-4fed-bd8c-e8450e3c221f","F":4}**

and I am getting another request for lock the same file and the lock string this time was as

> **{"S":"899d5d58-d6bd-4fed-bd8c-e8450e3c221f","F":6,"E":1,"C":"DF1","M":"df-c3797902412e","P":"1AA9FA35-67B7-493D-9AFD-85E62E8472EE","W":"df-15184ed4ac0e","B":"2C984395-61B7-499F-A10D-41FEF439A02F"}**

I can't figure it out how to get real lock string from this, and why I am getting this requests multiple times for same file ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WOPI Client (office online) Lock request](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38329948/wopi-client-office-online-lock-request)