# WOPI Client (office online) Lock request

Tags: office365, ms-wopi

I have strange response from WOPI client (i.e. Office Online) while locking the document, It provides me multiple locks in terms of short json string and long json string.

How could this be possible ? and even if it is, which one I should consider the valid and from whole json string, Which part of json string is actual lock ?

Response contains json string as below:

> {"F":6,"E":1,"C":"DF1","M":"df-8f3a7ae03629","P":"59F8D569-8001-4CF1-A5A2-E89C24E18A7F","W":"df-d81ca88d14b7","B":"4B9BA727-DD57-4CE5-8F3D-6A814191DB82","L":"df-94574cd614c8"}

Thanks in advance !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You store it as-is as 'a string'.

If you enabled SupportsExtendedLockLength in GetFileInfo then the size of the 'lock id' is at most 1024 characters, otherwise 256 characters. Make sure to account for this.

Comment: One strange thing is happening while getting this Lock request from Office Online. I am getting two or more Lock request for same file and same is happening for CheckFileInfo.
Can you pls help me with that, Why its happening ? Am I doing something wrong or what ? (wonder)

Comment: That is expected. A lock on an already locked file means that you have to 'extend' (refresh) the lock expiration time.

Comment: I'm getting "Session expired" only on Word Documents... First request -> Lock, Second request -> Lock with the long "wopi-lock" header... do you know, why I'm still getting "session expired"?